# One Large Model or Multiple Model Inheritance for SQL Performance?

Tags: sql, django, django-models

I have a website that allow users to post ads for items they want to sell. The items share some fields and differs in others. you might wanna sell a car or a house. You will have a title, created_date, description, ... etc fields that are shared . But you will have fields for car that aren't used for a house and so on. The type of ads is around 12 ad type like house, car or computer. There are two approaches:

1. To use a base model and inherit it by all other 12 types of ads so will have 13 tables in the DB.
2. To use a single model that have all the fields of all the ads types and will end up with one table and around 70 field (column in the table).

The second choice seems easy from Django CRUD side specially when querying and searching all the ads at the same time. What choice is better ? If I go with the second choice would I have any performance issues related to sql ?

Comment: Best practices and maintainability lead you to going the route of #1.  If you create a new ad in the future, you would add a new table, as opposed to changing an existing.  If you want to query just one type of ad, then you query the appropriate table and don't need to filter out the others.  If you wanted to list all ads, you can just use the parent and get the related fields.  Yes it would be kind of a pain if you needed to get all 70 fields from each of the tables, but since each ad has different fields anyways, your displays would have to be all different anyways.  #1.

Comment: Thanks Matt. The thing is when displaying the list of ads I might need to access some fields related to specific ad like car type and model or house rooms and baths. In this case I will end up with a lot of inner joins and that might be costly on the DB. If I need to add a new type I just add columns to the existing.table. In this case I will query one table with all the fields regardless of the type and in the display I will check the type of the ad and render the appropriate template. But my concern is one large table better or worse than many tables in terms of queries.

Comment: Ultimately you are talking about milliseconds.  You should focus on code maintainability.